# Ubuntu Install Alongside Windows Dilemma

Tags: dual-boot

*******2min** Video Included For Better First Hand View Of Problem*****

So I attempted to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows10. Initially I had Linux Mint installed alongside. My problems began after removing Linux Mint (I just flat-out deleted the 2 partitions containing Mint, leaving just a large unallocated space)  Now, as I am very much an amateur, I'll explain this the best I can..

(***clarification can be given upon request***)

Upon booting my laptop, I would normally hit **F9** (*Change Boot Order Screen*) which I would simply select my hard drive (seen in video as "Notebook HD") now this would normally bring me to a Grub Menu where I would select either Mint or Windows... Now seeing how I had just 'poorly' deleted Linux Mints partitions, I reboot my computer thinking that windows, being now the only operating system, would just boot directly into windows. However, after booting and selecting my hard drive, it had started went to some grub error command line..

*(******Just giving some pre-context as to what I am used to :/ oh! ..and If your wondering why I am booting this way, it's because I prefer to keep USB at the top of my boot priority******)*

...after installing Ubuntu (*which made me create an EFI partition during install***?**) I yet again proceeded to do exactly what I had been used to, which was selecting **F9** and then selecting my hard drive, expecting to arrive at a "grub menu".......this did not happen as was expected LOL!  I was just braught to a "grub error line"..... again!  So.. I then restart my laptop, select **F9**, and instead of selecting my hard drive, I notice at the top of the boot devices, Ubuntu itself has its own option  (*which I found odd*) ..after selecting, I get another error, however this time, the error is from what looks to be BIOS..

So I go back, and restart ONCE more.. but this time around, I do not select my Notebook HD, nor do I select the Ubuntu 'stand-alone' option. I select "boot from EFI file" which I found that I can navigate thru, to get the i stalled Ubuntu booted

I simply want to power onto a boot manager (grub/grub2/PloP/Graphical/Etc..  then being able to select either *Operating System **A*** or *Operating System **B***

[***Video Of Dilemma Click Here  -  Shared via OneDrive***](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AroiRct8P5NJmGj7qDMnAtEw1ypV)

Comment: if possible don't configure a password in bios, that is pointless and leads to you having to type a password when the system boots. the day you loose that password you will be forced to throw away the entire computer which is wastefull. both windows and ubuntu have system-lavel passwords. next have you tried booting onto any other drive? have you tried not typing F9 at all? what happens in both of those cases? please edit your post instead of replying. and while you're at it, please format your question, it's really jumbled and hard to read.

Comment: *Normally I would hit F9 and then select my Notebook HD, which would bring me to a Grub2 Menu (I like to keep USB at the top of my boot priority, hence the extra step there)* But priority if you have no USB connected the boot priority moves to the next step... you don't need to access the boot menu every time.

Comment: *I got rid of mint* << How did you do that? It seems to me that Mint was installed in EFI mode

Comment: I just deleted their  partitions (2 of them) .. I know that was a mistake

Comment: @guillermochamorro ..as to why I have to hit F9 everytime, I have a USB device stuck in my laptop, so instead of removing I just kept in and used it for distribution testing lol

Comment: It's not necessarely a mistake but the GRUB got broken. Ubuntu appears in your BIOS because it is installed in EFI mode (that's why it created an EFI partition). Your windows is 10 or 7?

Comment: Oh okay, yeah that makes sence.. I have Win10